# Android: OnTouch not responding.

Tags: android

I want an action to be performed when the view is touched. However, the touches do not respond. The app doesn't crash, it just seems to ignore it.

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View implements OnTouchListener
{
    static final int width = 100;
    static final int height = 50;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setOnTouchListener(mCustomDrawableView);            
        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
         {

        x = 400;  
        return true;
         }
         else {
             x = 300;
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {      
        int mCanvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        int mCanvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(R,x,y);


        if (y >= mCanvasHeight-100) {
            y = 0;
        }
        RectF oval = new RectF(x, y, x + width, y
                + height); // set bounds of rectangle
        Paint p = new Paint(); // set some paint options
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, p);
        canvas.restore();

        invalidate();


    }
}
```

I have tried a bunch of different code to fix it. None of it does anything except if I change setOnTouchListener(mCustomDrawable) to mCustomDrawableView.setOnTouchListener(this) the app crashes. There is a bunch more code in the activity that I did not put up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you believe that the `onTouch()` isn't firing because you're not seeing your graphics change in response to changes in `x` or whatever. If that's the case, it looks like you're missing a call to `invalidate()` in your touch handler to cause the `View` to redraw itself again (via a call to `onDraw()`).

Also, you have an `invalidate()` actually inside `onDraw()` itself which really shouldn't be there. It would certainly cause your `View` to redraw itself over and over - I suppose - so actually, I guess you *should* be seeing updates because that's there. But that isn't the way you should make a `View` animate; you should instead use a `Thread` or `Handler` to schedule a regular, periodic `invalidate()` - or some other means to regularly schedule an update.

Also there should be no need to implement 'OnTouchListener' when you can just override `onTouch()` as you have done. There are a couple of ways you can detect touch events for a `View`: (1) Override `onTouch()` as you have done, to get touch events on that `View`. (2) Register a listener using `setOnTouchListener()`. This latter option enables you to have a listener that listens to touch events from one `View` or multiple `View`s, and it also 'sees' touch events before a registered `View`'s own `onTouch()` sees them.

Another thing I see is that you're setting `x` to 400 when you get an ACTION_DOWN event but then you're setting it to 300 for any other kind of event such as an ACTION_MOVE. Considering it's actually quite difficult to keep your finger still enough to never cause a string of ACTION_MOVE events immediately after an ACTION_DOWN, perhaps you're just never seeing the graphics when `x` is at 400 or something.

You really need to post a complete example (for instance your code as you've posted has `setOnTouchListener(mCustomDrawableView)` where `mCustomDrawableView` has not been defined anywhere) together with specific errors from Logcat. Also, you should use the debugger to see if your `onTouch` ever executes (stick a breakpoint in it).

Also, you should accept some answers.